# How do I import a character?

Tags: import

Hi I'm a beginner in blender and I'm trying to download and import models into blender but it won't allow me to and I'm not sure how to do it now. I downloaded a model of a character from online and tryed to import it into blender as a rar file. I'm not sure how to do any of this can someone please give me an explanation on how to import a character model thing into blender :(

Comment: Probably, you first need to unzip the rar file and look at its content first. From that, indicate the file extensions you obtained.

Comment: As lemon mentioned, the .rar is an archive file that probably includes your model as well as possibly some other things such as a material (.mtl) file. Extract the archive and look for a file (liklely) with the extension: .obj, .fbx, .dae, or .gltf, then in blender, under the _file menu_, choose _import_ and then pick the corresponding format from the list - then choose your file.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett This comment is an answer. Please add it as such.

Comment: It does not show any file extensions other than .rar and it is in a zip file idk what to do now

Comment: .rar is usually an archive like .zip. Try to unpack it with something like [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org).